# Video Transcode with Android MediaCodec

Tags: java, android, android-mediacodec

Struggling with Android MediaCodec, I'm looking for a straight forward process to change the resolution of a video file in Android.

For now I'm trying a single thread transcoding method that makes all the work step by step so I can understand it well, and at high level it looks as follows:

```
public void TranscodeVideo()
{
    // Extract
    MediaTrack[] tracks = ExtractTracks(InputPath);

    // Decode
    MediaTrack videoTrack = tracks.Where(o => o.IsVideo).FirstOrDefault();
    MediaTrack rawVideoTrack = DecodeTrack(videoTrack);

    // Edit?
    // ResizeVideoTrack(rawVideoTrack);

    // Encode
    MediaFormat newFormat = MediaHelper.CreateVideoOutputFormat(videoTrack.Format);
    MediaTrack encodeVideodTrack = EncodeTrack(rawVideoTrack , newFormat);

    // Muxe
    encodeVideodTrack.Index = videoTrack.Index;
    tracks[Array.IndexOf(tracks, videoTrack)] = encodeVideodTrack;
    MuxeTracks(OutputPath, tracks);
}
```

Extraction works fine, returning a track with audio only and a track with video only. Muxing works fine combining again two previous tracks. Decoding works but I don't know how to check it, the raw frames on the track weight much more than the originals so I assume that it's right.

**Problem**

The encoder input buffer size is smaller than the raw frames size, and also related to the encoding configured format, so I assume that I need to resize the frames in some way but I don't find anything useful. I'm correct on this? I'm missing something? What is the way to go resizing Raw video frames? Any help? :S

**PD**

- Maybe you will notice that I'm using C# (Xamarin.Android) for more fun. But the underlaying API is of course Java.
- I'm using ByteBuffers, not Surfaces because it seems easier. I will be the next step using surfaces, any advice is welcome.
- I know that the single thread process is highly inefficient, but makes it simple. It will be another next step to connect the decoder output buffer to the encoder input buffer.
- I digged through [PhilLab](https://github.com/PhilLab/Android-MediaCodec-Examples/blob/master/EncodeAndMuxTest.java), [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/grafika/SoftInputSurfaceActivity.java) and [Bigflake](https://bigflake.com/mediacodec/ExtractMpegFramesTest_egl14.java.txt) examples but nothing seems to be very useful for me.
- Avoiding to use ffmpeg on Android.

Thank you everyone for your time.

Comment: Have you used libVLC? I've just integrated it into my app for RTSP streaming, it can handle transcoding and all that jazz that comes with vlc

Comment: Nope, looks cool, I will try, Could you give a quick C# example of transcoding with libVLC?

Comment: have a look at this thread, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15202315/how-to-set-encoder-buffer-size-created-by-mediacodec

Answer (score 1):

Going off of the comment above to implement libVLC

Add this to your app root's build.gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
       ...
       maven {
           url 'https://jitpack.io'
       }
   }
}
```

Add this to your dependent app's build.gradle

```
dependancies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.github.masterwok:libvlc-android-sdk:3.0.13'
}
```

Here is an example of loading an RTSP stream as an activity

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.camera_stream_layout);


    // Get URL
    this.rtspUrl = getIntent().getExtras().getString(RTSP_URL);
    Log.d(TAG, "Playing back " + rtspUrl);

    this.mSurface = findViewById(R.id.camera_surface);
    this.holder = this.mSurface.getHolder();

    ArrayList<String> options = new ArrayList<>();
    options.add("-vvv"); // verbosity
    //Add vlc transcoder options here

    this.libvlc = new LibVLC(getApplicationContext(), options);
    this.holder.setKeepScreenOn(true);
    //this.holder.setFixedSize();

    // Create media player
    this.mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(this.libvlc);
    this.mMediaPlayer.setEventListener(this.mPlayerListener);

    // Set up video output
    final IVLCVout vout = this.mMediaPlayer.getVLCVout();
    vout.setVideoView(this.mSurface);

    //Set size of video to fit app screen
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams videoParams = this.mSurface.getLayoutParams();
    videoParams.width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    videoParams.height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

    vout.setWindowSize(videoParams.width, videoParams.height);
    vout.addCallback(this);
    vout.attachViews();

    final Media m = new Media(this.libvlc, Uri.parse(this.rtspUrl));
    //Use this to add transcoder options m.addOption("vlc transcode options here");
    this.mMediaPlayer.setMedia(m);
    this.mMediaPlayer.play();
}
```

Here is the documentation of vlc transcoder options

https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo_New/

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the input buffer size of the encoder is smaller because it expects input to be of the specified dimensions. The encoder only, like the name suggests, encodes.

I read your question as more of a "why" than a "how" question so i'll only point you to where you'll find the "why's"

The decoded frame is a YUV image (is suggest to quickly skim through the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV)), usually [NV21](https://chromium.googlesource.com/libyuv/libyuv/+/HEAD/docs/formats.md#nv12-and-nv21) if i'm not mistaken but might be different from device to device. To do this i suggest you use a library as every every plane of the image needs to be scaled down differently and it usually takes care of filtering.Check out [libYUV](https://chromium.googlesource.com/libyuv/libyuv/+/refs/heads/master). If you are interested in the actual resizing algorithms check out [this](https://chromium.googlesource.com/libyuv/libyuv/+/HEAD/docs/filtering.md) and for implementations [this](https://chromium.googlesource.com/libyuv/libyuv/+/master/source/scale.cc).

If you are not required to handle the decoding and encoding with bytebuffers, i suggest to use a surface as you already mentioned. It has multiple benefits over decoding to bytebuffers.

- More memory efficient as there is no copy between the native buffer and app allocated buffer, the native buffers are simply geting swapped from and to the surface.
- If you plan to render the frame, be it for resizing or displaying, it can be done by the devices graphic processor. On how to do that check out BigFlakes [DecodeEditEncode](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/jb-mr2-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/DecodeEditEncodeTest.java) test.

In hope this answers some of your questions.